# Can I create a controller for layout in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a menu and I used a cookie in order to set the menu as selected by refreshing. The menu is common to all classes, so I put it in the _layout.cshtml, but the same time I want a controller for this layout because there some function to set the menu as highlight. Can I create a controller for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call `@Html.Action` or `@Hmtl.RenderAction` to invoke a controller from the view. But this borders on mixing of concerns, as now your view is actively calling your controller.

The better approach is often to pass the appropriate data to the view as part of your view model.

- [Somewhat related answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15716558/453277)
- [RenderAction method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728607%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

> But the same time I want a controller for this layout because there
>   some function to set the menu as highlight.

If you are doing something basic like highlighting the current page, there may be a simpler solution. You could put the current page ID into the `ViewBag` and retrieve that value in your main _Layout file and use it to select the appropriate item.

Comment: here we don't use viewbag.

Comment: Okay, then one of the other options I provided should work. I don't use ViewBag often, but it's good for small pieces of data like this.

Comment: What I need is I set the cookie, I have to set it as selected but when I put this url in to new tab it takes the old cookie.

Comment: Then perhaps go with the `RenderAction` approach that uses a controller to render the view, and have whatever cookie-related logic you need in there.

Comment: Is there any other article for referring?I am new in mvc

Comment: The article that @JonMalcolm linked is pretty good: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: ok.thanx..I will give you take your answer after getting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Partial actions may be what you looking for here - [this article may be some help](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). It relates to MVC2 but the principles remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

create an action for menu, and put menu ui in the view, and then call Html.Action("menu action name","controllern name") on layout page.