# .NET MVC4 Create or select foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I cant figure how to work this out, maybe you can help me. I have a `MVC4` project with a `customer model` and an `event model`.

When I access the `create view` for the event, I would like to select a customer (via `dropdownlist`, this is ok and working) or if the customer I want is not created yet, create it inside the event `create view` (not to close this view, open customer view, create customer, go back to event create view...). How can I do that? Any ideas?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968234/render-partial-view-from-other-controller This might help you. You need to render your view for creating a customer inside that current view. E.g; you could use Ajax to pop up a form.

Comment: What if the customer is created and i dont need to render that view?

Comment: Well that logic can be implemented in JavaScript for example. By means of a button "Create new customer" which pops up the view? Sergey Yanchenko Just answered what I mean! :)

Answer (score 2):

Can be done through the form and ess or partial view. I understand the question?

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-form">
        <form>
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
```

js

```
function openDialogForm() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
}


function closeDialogForm() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog('close');
}

function dialogForm() {
    if ($('#dialog-form').length) {
        $('#dialog-form').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 475,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            show: "slow",
            open: function () { $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () { $("#dialog-form").dialog('close'); }); }
        });
    }
```

Your implementation may be another.

Comment: Thats a good idea, i think its what im looking for. Just for finishing, if i create a new customer, can i return the code of that customer from the controller to the event create view via ajax?

Thanks everybody again!